# PHP timeago function like stackoverflow

Tags: php, datetime

I have this function for show timeago from unix timestamp:

```
function Timesince($original) {
    $original = strtotime($original);
    // array of time period chunks
    $chunks = array(
    array(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 , 'year'),
    array(60 * 60 * 24 * 30 , 'month'),
    array(60 * 60 * 24 * 7, 'week'),
    array(60 * 60 * 24 , 'day'),
    array(60 * 60 , 'hour'),
    array(60 , 'min'),
    array(1 , 'sec'),
    );

    $today = time(); /* Current unix time  */
    $since = $today - $original;

    // $j saves performing the count function each time around the loop
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($chunks); $i < $j; $i++) {

    $seconds = $chunks[$i][0];
    $name = $chunks[$i][1];

    // finding the biggest chunk (if the chunk fits, break)
    if (($count = floor($since / $seconds)) != 0) {
        break;
    }
    }

    $print = ($count == 1) ? '1 '.$name : "$count {$name}s";

    if ($i + 1 < $j) {
    // now getting the second item
    $seconds2 = $chunks[$i + 1][0];
    $name2 = $chunks[$i + 1][1];

    // add second item if its greater than 0
    if (($count2 = floor(($since - ($seconds * $count)) / $seconds2)) != 0) {
        $print .= ($count2 == 1) ? ', 1 '.$name2 : " $count2 {$name2}s";
    }
    }
    return $print;
}
```

This Worked for me. But i need to print timeago only for 3 days, after 3 days need to show normal date like :`01/01/2015`. in action stackoverflow work with this method.

how do create this ?

Comment: you must look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

step1 : calulate difference

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2007-03-24");
$date2 = new DateTime("2009-06-26");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
//echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, //".$interval->d." days ";
```

Step 2:

use if condition to show off your date

```
if($interval->d > 3 || $interval->m >0 || $interval->y >0 ){
// echo out your date in your required format
}
```

thanks to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php?rq=1)
Use this as an idea and approach....

Comment: If the difference will be 1 month, then `$interval->d` will return 0